# Netgear WNR3500L - Repeater Mode

Tags: wireless-router, repeater

the Netgear WNR3500L officially says that it supports a repeater funciton. I got the repeater set up -- I had the main router upstairs, then the repeater downstairs, broadcasting the same SSID -- but I couldn't connect while I was downstairs. That is, when I was upstairs, my computer could connect fine. However, when I was in the downstair's router's "field" or "broadcast" I couldn't connect.

My network is totally wireless (printers, laptop, etc.) -- no ethernet connections whatsoever.

Any ideas? I was looking at the opensource firmware over at DD-WRT, perhaps that would help?

Thanks -- Kyle